# Set tls_reqcert never with spring ldap

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring LDAP to connect with ldaps to a server.

Is possible to set tls_reqcert never?

for now i have in application.properties file:

```
ldap.url=ldaps://192.168.0.0:636
ldap.userDn=
ldap.password=
ldap.base=
ldap.clean=true
ldap.maxActive=350
```

i try with:

```
public class SslLdap extends DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy {

    private static final String SIMPLE_AUTHENTICATION = "simple";

    protected void applyAuthentication(LdapContext ctx, String userDn, String password) throws NamingException {


    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/home/user/truststore.jks");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","secret");

    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, SIMPLE_AUTHENTICATION);
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userDn);
    ctx.addToEnvironment(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not. But if you want to use SSL with Spring Ldap you can do this:

1) Add truststore (with self certificate) into /WEB-INF/ folder.

You must create a class that LdapContextSource like this:

```
public class SslLdap extends LdapContextSource{

this.setUrl("ldaps://url:636");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ctx.getRealPath( "WEB-INF/truststore.jks" ));
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", keyStorePassword);    


    super.afterPropertiesSet();

    Hashtable<String, Object> envProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

    envProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    envProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://url:636");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "userDN");
    envProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass"); 


    envProps.put("java.naming.security.protocol", "ssl");
    envProps.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool", "true");

    super.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(envProps);
    super.afterPropertiesSet();

}
```

and in your Bean set:

```
<!-- LDAPS config -->
    <bean id="contextSourceTarget" class="com.yourpackage.SslLdap">
        <property name="url" value="${ldap.url}" />
        <property name="base" value="${ldap.base}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.userDn}" />
        <property name="password" value="${ldap.password}" />
        <property name="pooled" value="false" />

    </bean>
```

I think the property you can delete.